# Link parsing error, preview is fine

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961816/proper-way-of-writing-a-hql-in-query/961865#961865), the second link is not properly displayed, but the edit page with the preview works as expected.

### Displayed answer

[Displayed answer http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/6540/solinkparseerror.png](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/6540/solinkparseerror.png)

### Edit screen + preview

[Edit screen + preview http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/1221/solinkparseerroredit.png](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/1221/solinkparseerroredit.png)

Comment: Your image links are broken. Can you fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. Links aren't expected to have spaces, so when a space is present in an anchor link (which happens a *lot* in Javadocs), it must be encoded as `%20`.

The previewing formatter does seem to be too permissive, though. It definitely shouldn't let anything through that won't work in the real formatter.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still concerned about the preview working and not the actual transformation.

Comment: There are several cases in which I've noticed the preview window behaving differently. Offhand, I can think of markdown inside words (like word**bold**word) and links with backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Links should not have spaces.
2. If you feel strongly that the javascript preview needs to be improved, [it is open source, have at it!](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/)